# Remove Button Styling From f.submit in Rails Form

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a simple form that simply sets the `#active` attribute to true/false. Within the form there is only one single `hidden_field`.  Here is how I currently have the submit button for the form looking when the `#active` status is true.

[image: active button]

When clicked, the form will submit and change the #active attribute to `false`.  When redisplayed it will look like this:

[image: inactive button].

Basically the form functions as a toggle switch that behind the scenes submits a form which toggles an attribute to true/false.

It works wonderfully.  However, I do not want any of the default `button` styling.  I don't want that gray box or the border.  Instead: I only want to show that font-awesome glyphicon for the button, and that is it.

Here is the code I currently have which displays the glyphicon with the gray button css:

```
<td>
  <%= form_for blog do |f| %>

    <% if blog.active %>
      <%= f.hidden_field :active, value: false  %>
    <% else %>
      <%= f.hidden_field :active, value: true  %>
    <% end  %>

    <% if blog.active? %>
      <%= f.button do %>
        <i class="fa fa-toggle-on fa-2x text-success" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      <% end %>
    <% else %>
      <%= f.button do %>
        <i class="fa fa-toggle-off fa-2x text-danger" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      <% end %>
    <% end  %>
  <% end %>
</td>
```

**Question:** How can I take the button styling off of the `f.submit` button and only have the glyphicon to represent the submit button?

Comment: Are you using bootstrap? The styling must be coming from one of the classes that you added. I would potentially add the css tag to this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would love to hear if there is a better solution. Basically all I did was added a new css class which sets the `background` property to `none` and the `border` property to `none`.

```
<% if blog.active? %>
  <%= f.button, class: 'remove-submit-btn-style' do %>
    <i class="fa fa-toggle-on fa-2x text-success" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  <% end %>
<% else %>
  <%= f.button, class: 'remove-submit-btn-style' do %>
    <i class="fa fa-toggle-off fa-2x text-danger" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  <% end %>
<% end  %>
```

And then in `app/assets/stylesheets/application.scss`

```
.remove-submit-btn-style {
  background: none;
  border: none;
}
```

[image: active]

[image: inactive]